# Java regular expression with 10+ groups

Tags: java, regex

I want to understand how Java will interpret

```
(one)(one)(one)(one)(one)(one)(one)(one)(one)(one)(two)\11
```

Will it try to match the first group and the literal `1` at the end or will it try to match the 11th group? How can I match the 11th group?

Comment: I tried to rephrase and clarify your question, apologies if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java regex would be:

```
"(one)(one)(one)(one)(one)(one)(one)(one)(one)(one)(two)\\11"
```

And it will match 11th captured group.

As per Javadoc:

> In Perl, \1 through \9 are always interpreted as back references; a backslash-escaped number greater than 9 is treated as a back reference if at least that many subexpressions exist, otherwise it is interpreted, if possible, as an octal escape. In this class octal escapes must always begin with a zero. In this class, \1 through \9 are always interpreted as back references, and a larger number is accepted as a back reference if at least that many subexpressions exist at that point in the regular expression, otherwise the parser will drop digits until the number is smaller or equal to the existing number of groups or it is one digit.